# Make Soft Body more rigid in one direction

Tags: physics, constraints, soft-body, axis

I want to make a soft body simulation that is very stretchy along Y and Z axis, but almost doesn't deform along the X axis - doesn't bend when pushed or doesn't squish. Think of a tube or a ring that stretches to accommodate the ball passing through it, but it's length remains fixed, and the ball doesn't cause it to squish and shorten.

Is it possible to make?
I'm quite new to Blender, so excuse me if it's obvious.
One idea I had is to add additional invisible vertexes and edges to the soft body face that I don't want to deform that act as kind of ropes, and set them as goal. The problem is that they also limit the sideways movements of the verts along that face, and I would like it to be very elastic.

Thank you!